# Powershell get-content where-object

Tags: powershell

Morning, I am new to the world of Windows PowerShell and wondered if someone could advise on the following. 
I am searching a txt file for a certain string of text.

```
Get-Content -Path "filepath" | Where-Object {
  $_ -like '*string*'
} | Out-File c:\output.txt
```

This works OK for me but I want to be a little smarter and only pull back the string for that particular day. 
I've tried to use the following

```
Get-Content -Path "filepath" | Where-Object {
  $_ -like Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%y" + '*string*'
} | Out-File c:\output.txt
```

The line in the text file always starts with the date in that format but then I need to check for a string in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `Get-Date` in parentheses:

```
Get-Content -Path "filepath" | Where-Object {
  $_ -like (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%y") + '*string*'
} | Out-File c:\output.txt
```

Comment: thanks very much for this. This works perfectly, however, what I need to do now is minus 1 day as the result set would be for yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying several attempts, I've noticed that the file I am querying has the date format in MM/dd/yyyy format so this was why I wasn't finding anything.

Also, I needed to look for the previous day as well so added a little bit more in.

Tweaked it slightly and works now

get-content -path "location of text file" | where-object {$_ -like ("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f (get-date).AddDays(-1)) + '*Sqlserver*'} | out-file filename

Thanks everyone for your help